# How would I use shared properties or function in interface?

Tags: vb.net

In vb.net you cannot use shared properties in interface.

I am implementing something like this

```
Public Interface iSumableObject

    ReadOnly Property Keys As Generic.List(Of String)
    ReadOnly Property valueArrays As Generic.List(Of Double) ' this generic.list(of double) must have all exact same number of elements. how do we "enforce" that in interface

    Function StringReport(valueArrays As Generic.List(Of Double), key As String) As String ' This should actually be a shared function. Now wehave to instantiate an object to a class to do this
    Function sortParameter(valueArrays As Generic.List(Of Double)) As Double
End Interface
```

Basically I want every class that implement iSumableObject to customize it's StringReport and sortParameter function.

However, when they do that, they are not working with the class straight. The content of `StringReport` and `sortParameter` depends only on some of valueArrays across several `iSumableObject`.

In other word, `StringReport` and `sortParameter` should have been a shared method. It's use is not linked to any particular instance of iSumableObject.

Yet I can't create shared interface.

So what should I do instead?

Basically I want every implementation of iSumableObject to have it's own implementation of StringReport

However, StringReport doesn't depend on a particular iSumableObject object. It takes valueArrays As Generic.List(Of Double) as input and that's it.

Comment: It sounds like you should create an abstract (`MustInherit`) base class.  It's a class and so can have `Shared` members.

Comment: the thing with new inheritance is you can only do it once.... Hmmmm.... I suppose. But my objects will most likely inherit from other more prominent data. Actually what's the logic of preventing not to have shared interface? Basically I want to have some helper function that works only on an implementation of a class that implements iSumableObject

Comment: An interface, as the name suggests, is supposed to define only the interface without regard for the implementation.  How could you possibly have a `Shared` member declared in an interface and then have each type that implemented that interface provide a different implementation for that member?  How could different types share something if they all have their own implementation of it?

Comment: they share the interface but not the implementation. One class, may for example, print a different report in stringReport than another class

Comment: Then it's not shared, so it's not `Shared`.

Comment: Of course it's shared. The report does not involve any particular object of the class. The function handles a group of such class.

Comment: Wait, of course the implementation that they don't share is shared? Are you reading your own comments? I'm done wasting my time with this.

Comment: VB.Net has "static" key word for members. Will it help you to use Keys and valueArrays across the instances of iSumableObject.